# Can trees be generalized to allow any traversable sub-tree?

Tags: haskell, tree, type-families, traversable

`Data.Tree` uses a list to represent the subtree rooted at a particular node. Is it possible to have two tree types, for example one which uses a list and another which uses a vector? I want to be able to write functions which don't care how the sub-tree is represented concretely, only that the subtree is traversable, as well as functions which take advantage of a particular subtree type, e.g. fast indexing into vectors.

It seems like type families would be the right tool for the job, though I've never used them before and I have no idea how to actually define the right family.

If it matters, I'm not using the containers library tree instance, but instead I have types

`data Tree a b = Node a b [Tree a b] deriving (Show, Foldable, Generic)`

and

`data MassivTree a b = V a b (Array B Ix1 (MassivTree a b))`

where the latter uses vectors from [massiv](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv-0.6.0.0).

Comment: See the [`Cofree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.6/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html) datatype; `Cofree f a = a :< f (Cofree f a)`

Comment: And its dual; [`Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.6/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a typeclass - in fact the typeclass you need probably already exists.

Consider this:

```hs
data Tree t a = Tree a (t (Tree t a))
```

Argument `t` is a higher-kinded type which represents a container of `a`s.

Now define a set of Tree operations, constrained on `Traversable` like so:

```
:: (Foldable t) => Tree t a -> b
```

And you can now create and manipulate trees that use any `Foldable`. You would need to choose the right typeclass for the set of operations you want - `Functor` may be enough, or you may want `Traversable` if you are doing anything with monadic actions. You can choose the typeclass on a per-function basis, depending on what it does.

You can now define `Tree` types like so:

```hs
type ListTree a = Tree [] a
type MassivTree r ix a = Tree (Array r ix) a
```

You can also define instance-specific functions, with access to a full range of functionality:

```hs
:: ListTree a -> b
-- or
:: Tree [] a -> b
```

Happy Haskelling!

Comment: Thanks. Was able to get it make my current  tree type a specialization of Tree t a b with minimal re-writing (just had to make it an instance of Show manually). And all the old functions still work.

Comment: This is just `Cofree`

Comment: @xgrommx Can you expand on that?

Comment: Tree is Cofree here

Comment: I understand. can you explain the significance? I assume there is some category-theoretical way of looking at that. There's no need to give things new, obscure names without some sort of benefit. What is a "comonad homomorphism from another comonad that is is equivalent to a natural transformation", and is there a reason for me to care in this context?

Comment: @AriFordsham The reason to care is that there's already a library that provides this data type and a bunch of operations on it, including folding, unfolding, traversing, zipping, extracting values, and more. That's a bunch of code you don't have to write yourself.

Comment: Granted (although it seems in this case the OP *wanted* to write this code himself). It's just a shame we have to bonk new Haskellers over the head with category-theoretic jargon, and when asked, we cannot provide a concrete justification about what the category theory gives us.